# How to return current Page and fetch value by using @Via("resource")?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, aem-6, sling-models

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class , defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class Solution {

    @ScriptVariable
    Page currentPage;

    @Inject
    @Via("resource")
    @Default(values="Heading of Business")
    String heading;

  
    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }
    

    String getPageTitle() {
        return currentPage.getTitle();
    }

}
```

HTL part:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="com.training.core.sling.models.Solution"></sly>
<div>IsCurrent page  Name :${model.pageTitle}</div>
<div>Is heading:${model.heading}</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what is the issue, what are you getting instead, etc.